# Binding a ListBox to an interface's properties in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7

I'm having issues getting my databinding working for a ListBox. I suspect it's because I'm trying to databind against an interface rather than a class.

My C# code:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    interface IFoo
    {
        string Bar { get; }
    }

    class Fizz
    {
        private class Buzz : IFoo
        {
            public string Bar { get { return "something"; } }
        }

        public IEnumerable<IFoo> GetFoo()
        {
            List<Buzz> items = new List<Buzz>();
            // Populate items
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to do databinding with the output from `Fizz::GetFoo()`, it doesn't work. My XAML looks like:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text="Bar:" />
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Bar}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When I run it, I see the text for the first TextBlock but not the second. I see errors in the Output window similar to this:

```
    System.Windows.Data Error: Cannot get 'Bar' value (type 'System.String') from 'Buzz' (type 'MyNamespace.Fizz+Buzz'). BindingExpression: Path='Bar' DataItem='Buzz' (HashCode=100433959); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String').. System.MethodAccessException: Attempt to access the method failed: MyNamespace.Fizz+Buzz.get_Bar()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.InternalGetValue(PropertyInfo thisProperty, Object obj, Object[] index, StacA first chance exception of type 'System.MethodAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Am I doing something wrong or is what I'm trying to do just not possible?

Comment: Can you post code that you use to initialize DataContext using GetFoo()??

Comment: What is `listBox1` actually bound to? You haven't included quite enough code.

Comment: I think it is safe to assume that he is setting `DataContext = fizz.GetFoo();`  That isn't the problem, as it is clear in the message that the property is there... but there is an access violation.

Comment: Correct, there were no problems with DataContext so I left it out to try to keep the question simpler. Making types public fixed the issue.

Comment: This is nasty, because it works in WP8. It's WP7 or the SL version respectively which screws it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like everything in your chain needs to be public (and your `List` needs to be `List<IFoo>` instead of `List<Bar>`):

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Bar { get; }
}

public class Fizz
{
    public class Buzz : IFoo
    {
        public string Bar { get { return "something"; } }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IFoo> GetFoo()
    {
        List<IFoo> items = new List<IFoo>();
        // Populate items
        return items;
    }
}
```

The problem you are running into has to do with reflection across assemblies.  The Silverlight code is reflecting on your internal class and interface (classes and interfaces are `internal` unless otherwise specified).  Even `Buzz` needs to be public because it still needs to reflect upon that class, which is private, so it fails.

Obviously, if you were not using data binding here, the code would work fine.  You would have access to `IFoo` even though `Buzz` is private.  But, once you bring reflection into the mix, you have to start making things public, unfortunately.

Comment: This solved it for me, thanks! Note that I didn't have to change the type of the items from List<Bar> to List<IFoo>.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Buzz` class is private, and so the binding engine cannot access the members of that class to perform binding on.

Comment: That's an obvious conclusion, but may not be the only one - i.e. the datacontext of the ListBox could be all screwed up as well.

Comment: Yup, and if I'm wrong then the poster can always comment and tell me that my solution doesn't work and we can work towards a solution :)

Comment: @slugster: I suppose, but the error message he put out there makes it clear that this is an access violation.  In addition, we know this code won't work even if the `DataContext` is set properly (a fair assumption) because everything needs to be public -- the interface, the outer class and the inner class -- for reflection to work.